# How to implement the MVC architecture in the `<ROOT_APP>/lib` directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, directory

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2. In the `<ROOT_APP>/lib/my_plugin` directory I developed a "plugin" and now I am considering:

- to implement the MCV (Model-Control-View) architecture in the `<ROOT_APP>/lib/my_plugin` directory;
- to make those related controllers, helpers and so on available to my application (where needed).

Is it possible to make that? If so, how? What do you advice about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider making a mountable application if you need controllers, models and views. Devise is a good gem to look at to get an example of how this is done. It'll be a lot simpler than duplicating the entire structure of a Rails app in lib.

Comment: There is some documentation (or book) other than the [official](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) where I can "really" (that is, in detail) understand how to *implement* from scratch and *use* engines?

Comment: Other than Ryan's guide he posted below, I can't think of anything. You've got the basic knowledge already though. Just think of it as an application that's going to live inside your other application.

You've got controllers, models, views and everything else you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend, along with jbarket, to not build your plugin into your application. Instead, build it as an engine (following [this guide about engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)) and maintain it as a separate entity that your application depends on in its `Gemfile.`